# doubly linked lists initiallisation

Tags: c++, c++17, doubly-linked-list

Hello so i'm something new to linked lists and data structrs generally so i want to creat two functions one initiallise the doubly linked list and the other one print it but when i compile it it doesnt print anything where did i miss exactly (i heard that i should use the debugger but i didnt understand how to use it on Dev c++ IDE)

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{   int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *previous;
};
Node *head,*end;


Node* insertion()
{   
    Node *first_node =new Node;
    if (head==NULL || first_node==NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        
    first_node->data=10;
    first_node->previous=NULL;
    first_node->next=NULL;
    head=first_node;
    end=first_node;
    return head;
}
void affiche()
{
    Node *current;
    current=head;
    if(head==NULL)
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while(current->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<current->data <<" ";
        current=current->next;
    }
}
int main()
{

    Node *MyList=insertion();
    affiche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *i heard that i should use the debugger but i didnt understand how to use it on Dev c++ IDE* No better time then now to start learning.  debugging is a critical tool for programing so the earlier you get better with it, the better your life will be.

Comment: To use the debugger you have to have a breakpoint to start debugging.

Comment: can you be more specific about that breakpoint this what i didnt understand how to use it while debugging

Comment: It’s a point, read this: https://sites.google.com/site/sirhans/Home/oop-2008/links/how-to-debug-in-dev-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
while(current->next!=NULL)
```

to

```
while(current!=NULL)
```

Your version stops printing the list too early.

(But please learn how to use a debugger, you would have found this error very quickly with a debugger).

**EDIT**

You also need to remove this

```
if (head==NULL || first_node==NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

`head==NULL` is initially true and `first_node==NULL` is never true. (`new` never returns NULL). Since `head==NULL` is initially true your program is always going to quit at the point.

**EDIT(2)**

And remove this

```
if(head==NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Why do you think printing an empty list is an error that means you have to exit the program? It's perfectly OK to print an empty list.

Comment: thanks but it was orriginaly like the second and it didn't work so i change it to the first one to see if it will work or no

Comment: You have other errors (really learn to use a debugger).

Comment: oh it works thanks bro and i've started learning how to use the debugger thanks for the explainig and advices